# Code running perfectly for http url but showing error:504 (gateway timeout) for https url

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse, http-status-code-504

Code running fine for http URL but showing error when URL changes to HTTPS 
ERROR: 504(GATEWAY_TIMEOUT)

```
        List<TableauSite> SitesList = new List<TableauSite>();
        string url = server + "/api/" + TableauServerVersion.version + "/sites";
        HttpWebRequest wc = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
        wc.Method = "GET";
        wc.Headers.Add("x-tableau-auth", signedInObj.ACCESS_TOKEN);
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse wr = wc.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.Load(wr.GetResponseStream());
            SitesList = helperFunction(serverinfo, xmldoc, server,signedInObj);
            return SitesList;
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            //Catch failed request and return the response code
            response = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode.ToString();
            ErrorHandling.getException(we);
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like the server you are connecting to requires HTTPS (Secure) and you are only send non secure.

Comment: Server is secure

Comment: Your request is missing required headers.  Can you connect with an Browser manually?  If you can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and capture the browser first request and compare the header in request with your non work request.

Comment: No i cannot connect browser manually, it is at client side... didn't have access

Comment: The https is using TLS for security.  HTTP uses TCP as the transport layer.  So a TLS connection is established using TCP as part of going secure.  See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest?view=netframework-4.8